# Convert String to Date in CASE expression Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case, to-date, to-char

I'm using the following `CASE` expression, but I want the field to be a Date and not string format:

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = '01/01/1800' THEN '01/01/2029'  
         ELSE TO_CHAR(DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
     END as ENDDATE,
```

I tried adding in `TO_DATE(` before the `TO_CHAR`, but I keep getting an error on the `Then` part. Any pointers to how to successfully add in `TO_DATE` to this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use date literal (which is always `yyyy-mm-dd`) and compare it directly to your `date_column`:

```
case when trunc(date_column) = date '1800-01-01' then date '2029-01-01'
     else date_column
end as enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
case when date_column=to_date('01/01/1800','dd/mm/yyyy') then to_date('01/01/2029','dd/mm/yyyy')
     else date_column end as enddate
from dual;
```

You just have to make sure all the possible outcomes of the case statement belong to the same data type.